# VM (created through Vagrant) is not listing the inet in eth1

Tags: virtualization, ip, ifconfig, vagrant

I created a VM through `vagrant` with the following in vagrant file:

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
......
.....
..
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

Note the warnings here :

```
default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
```

`vagrant ssh` and entered into the VM

put the command: `ip addr show`

Notice: inet is not displayed in eth1

[image]